# SilverStripe 3 - Options for <% loop %>

Tags: php, loops, silverstripe

Is there a list of all the options I can add to a loop?

I don't know if options is the right name for it. I mean these

```
<% loop Dataobject.Reverse %>
<% loop Dataobject.Limit() %>
```

Can someone tell me everything that's possible here? And what the correct name for it is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is an error in your question, it is `<% loop $DataList.xxx %>` or  `<% loop $ArrayList.xxx %>` (see, you are looping a list of DataObjects)

well, `loop` is basically just a `foreach` loop

so, for example:

```
<% loop $DataList.Reverse %>$Title<% end_loop %>
```

is kindof the same as:

```
<?php 
foreach($dataList->reverse() as $item) { 
    echo $item->Title; 
}
```

'kindof' the same, because in fact the template does some checking and casting for you (eg it does not throw and error if Title is not set), and a loop can only loop SilverStripe lists, not arrays

---

tl;dr; / the conclusion

`loop` has no options at all
the options that you speak of are methods that exist on the list that you want to loop.
the 2 lists php classes that you would normally loop are:

- DataList [api docs for class DataList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#methods)
- ArrayList [api docs for class ArrayList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ArrayList.html#methods)

see the list of methods in the API docs for what methods are available.

obviously not all methods are meant to be used to loop,
only those that return a `DataList` or `ArrayList` will be useful.
you can see what they return from the first column of the table.

for example:

```
public ArrayList limit( integer $length, integer $offset = 0 )
```

means:

- it is public (so its accessable, private or protected ones will not be available in template)
- it returns ArrayList
- the name is `limit`
- the parameters are a number length and an number offset

so you can do: `<% loop $List.limit(10,5) %>`

---

further reading:

some methods in that list do not show parameters but actually do have them, this is because they are dynamic and the API docs fail to display that.

example:

```
public ArrayList filter( )
```

can be used like this (I think, never tried it):

```
<% loop $List.filter('Name', 'Zauberfisch') %>
```

---

you can also add your own methods by creating an `Extension` and adding this Extension to `DataList` and `ArrayList`

Comment: PHP (hence SilverStripe) is case insensitive on method names: `<% loop $List.LIMIT(10,5) %>` will work too.