# Silverstripe loop

Tags: templates, silverstripe

```
<%loop $Video.Limit(4) %><% end_loop %>
<%loop $Video.Limit(5,9) %><% end_loop %>
```

Two divs are being used to display the data,the above code is not working.
Any help is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as [@Zauberfisch stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20585399/4137738) you need to use `limit(4)` (note the lowercase) in your template.

Another problem is the missing space between `<%` and `loop`.

Assuming $Video is some kind of `SS_List` (ArrayList or DataList), you could try

```
//show the first 4 videos
<% loop $Video.limit(4) %>$Title <% end_loop %> 
//gets the next 9 videos, offset is 5
<% loop $Video.limit(9,5) %>$Title <% end_loop %>
```

See [API docs for limit](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_limit)

Comment: i was also wondering about the missing space before 'loop', but tried it and doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: PHP is case insensitive: `<% loop $Video.LIMIT(4) %>` will work too.